# present perfect orr past simple for repeated actions that are finished

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I **have been** on vacation in Paris for two weeks (ongoing action) I **went** or **have been** five times in the Eiffel Tower (I am sure I will not go another  time there during this vacation)

My vacation are not finished at the time of writing but I'm sure that I will not go another time to the Eiffel tower, would I use past simple or present perfect?

I think present perfect is a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP's choice of the present perfect is not OK. The use of the present perfect is more indicative of the possibility of doing something again. So the OP should use the past simple.

Comment: Imagine now that my vacation are totally finished, shall I say "When I was in vacation in Paris, I had been or went 5 times in the Eiffel tower. Regarding the answer of my first question I would choose past simple.