# Tenses: which one is correct

Tags: tense

Which is correct:

I have been to Australia 2 times in 5 years.

I went to Australia 2 times in 5 years.

Comment: The first one is correct if you are talking about the last five years (except that I would say _twice_ rather than _two times_). You could use the simple past tense if you were talking about a particular five-year period further back in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [present perfect orr past simple for repeated actions that are finished](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64686/present-perfect-orr-past-simple-for-repeated-actions-that-are-finished)